# Multi level aggregate lookup in mongo DB

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

So here's my simplified data structure:

Test (test):

```
[{
   _id:1,
   name:"test1"
}]
```

Test Schedule (test_scheduled):

```
[{
   _id:2,
   testId:1,
   batchIds:[1,2]
}]
```

Batch (batch):

```
[{
    _id:1,
    name:"batch 1" 
},{
    _id:2,
    name:"batch 2"
}]
```

Now, this is how I need the result to look like:

```
{ // Test
    _id:1,
    name:"test1",
    test_scheduled:[{ // test scheduled
       _id:2,
       batches:[{ // batches
          _id:1,
          name:"batch 1"
       },{
          _id:2,
          name:"batch 2"
       }]
    }]
}
```

I am able to achieve the first level lookup using this:

```
 [ // querying test collection
  {
    $lookup:{
      from: "tests_scheduled",
      localField: "_id",
      foreignField: "testId",
      as: "tests_scheduled"
    }
  },
  {
    $match:{
      _id:new DB.Mongo.ObjectID(testId)
    }
  }
]
```

But I am not able to figure out how to extend the query to get a second level lookup to get batches names in the same query too.

Thanks for your help